# Unknown column ‘x.y’ in ‘where clause’ when using sqlRestriction with createAlias

Tags: grails, grails-orm

i have a withCriteria  with `createAlias("xRecords", "x", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)`

When i try to do `sqlRestriction("x.y > 1")` I get the error:

> Unknown column ‘x.y’ in ‘where clause’

`y` is a column in `xRecords`.

What am i missing?

Comment: Doesn't that just create an alias in your hibernate queries?  I don't think that alias is valid for SQL restrictions that are passed verbatim to the database.

Comment: @Daniel that's true but i'm wondering what name i should use on the restriction..

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I'd suspect you can either write pure SQL (using left joins in your query and adding this to the 'where' block accordingly) or you could just do something like "x { gt("y", 1) }" to use the alias in your criteria.

Comment: @Daniel unfortunately `x { gt("y", 1) }` didn't work... I think i'm close to a solution. If it works, I'll share it as an answer and let you know.